# Sonar Cube throws bug saying as "is null on at least one execution path."

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sonarqube, nullable, sonarlint

c# code

```
if (numlist.Any())
{
    numlist.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Number == request.Number).ValCount = request.Count;
}
```

Sonar Cube throws bug message saying as 'numlist.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Number == request.Number)' is null on at least one execution path.

I have tried to put nullable ? like this -> numlist? but it doesn't works.

Can you please assist how to resolve this issue

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` can return null so this is dangerous code.

Comment: Even if your list has elements (cf. `Any()`), it does not mean that you always have a number that matches the `FirstOrDefault` condition. The null issue is located on what the `FirstOrDefault` will return. So it is possible that you do `null.ValCount`.
You should handle the case where the `FirstOrDefault` returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code says:

```
// if there are any entries in numlist
if (numlist.Any())
{
    // find the first entry whose Number matches the request,
    // or if not found, return the default for the numlist's
    // type, which is null according to the warning
    numlist.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Number == request.Number)
        // set the ValCount property of the result to request.Count
        .ValCount = request.Count;
}
```

The problem is that [`FirstOrDefault(predicate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-8.0) returns a default value if none of the elements in the source collection matched the predicate.

In other words: it's not guaranteed that there's any entry in `numlist` that has `Number == request.Number`, in which case `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null`.

You can't assign `ValCount` on `null`, that will throw a NullReferenceException.

Furthermore, combining `Any()` and `FirstOrDefault()` is superfluous in this case. You can refactor the code like this:

```
var requestedItem = numlist.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Number == request.Number);

if (requestedItem == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot find item with number '{request.Number}'");
}

requestedItem.ValCount = request.Count;
```

Guarding execution (and at the same time pleasing the static analysis), guaranteeing that a situation which you think might never happen, will never happen.

Comment: Just a wee nitpick, but if we want to throw an exception when the item is missing, wouldn't it be better to use `numlist.First(c => c.Number == request.Number).ValCount = request.Count;` ?

Comment: IMHO no, because `First()` will throw a nondescript "sequence contains no (matching) elements" exception. I hate `First()` and `Single()`'s default message, gives you nothing to go with.

Comment: That or `Sequence contains no matching element` - but I take your point.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Thanks for your answer. I have additionally formatted using `null coalescing ( ?? ) operator` like as following - `var requestedItem = numlist.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Number == request.Number) ?? throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot find item with number '{request.Number}'");`

Comment: @Developer no problem, I've got enough points as it stands. Happy to be of help.